# Image to byte C++ CLI

Tags: изображения, c++-cli, byte, консоль

Я новичок в написании кода на C++, пока только разбираюсь и не понимаю как перевести картинку в байты, у меня есть код на C#, он работает, хочу написать подобный на C++, но не понимаю как. Вот код на C#, помогите пожалуйста.

```
public static byte[] ImageToByte2(Image img)
    {
        byte[] result;
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            img.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Png);
            result = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

UPD:
Заменил некоторые знаки, но ошибки все еще остались

```
static BYTE ImageToByte(System::Drawing::Image^ img)
{
    BYTE result;
    System::Byte result;
    System::IO::MemoryStream memoryStream;
    {
        img->Save(memoryStream, System::Drawing::Imaging::ImageFormat::Png);
        result = memoryStream.ToArray();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Ошибка: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kzVW.jpg и https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebmmY.jpg

Comment: Повторяю в стопицотый раз: C++ и C++/CLI - это два **разных** языка.

Comment: Ну вот к примеру, по вашему совету сделал, не работает. 
скриншот с ошибками: https://imgur.com/D2IMj8j
скриншот полного кода: https://imgur.com/amv2x28

Comment: возникла новая ошибка: https://imgur.com/7VQIdXQ

Comment: отредактировал вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так. У меня сейчас нет под рукой C++/CLI, проверить не могу.

```
public:
static array<Byte>^ ImageToBytes(Image^ image)
{
    MemoryStream^ memoryStream = gcnew MemoryStream();
        
    image->Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat::Png);

    return memoryStream->ToArray();
}
```

Откройте пространства имён, чтобы код стал лаконичней:

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::IO;
using namespace System::Drawing;
using namespace System::Drawing::Imaging;
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает.

Comment: Извините за еще один вопрос, решил делать еще одну функцию аналогичным способом, появились другие ошибки) https://imgur.com/eK6DWo9
Скриншот кода - https://imgur.com/ju0v8e3